# How do I correctly use jQuery once()?

Tags: javascript

Due to a module, the Drupal behavior I implemented is called five times instead of once.

```js
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myFunction = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // …
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

How do I correctly use jQuery `once()`?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7, or Drupal 8? The method is slightly different depending on the version.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `$.once()`, which is available in both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8. The code called inside `$.once()` will only be executed a single time for the HTML element it is called on.

For Drupal 7, you can do this.

```js
(function ($, Drupal) {

  function someElementWatcher(context) {
    // $.once acts like $.each, and loops through the found elements.
    // The code inside $.once() will act on each element in the jQuery object
    // a single time.
    $(context).find(".some_element").once("some-arbitrary-but-unique-key", function () {
      // $(this) refers to the current instance of $(".some_element")
      $(this).click(function () {
        // Do something clicky.
      });
    });
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.someUniqueKey = {
    attach:function (context) {
      someElementWatcher();
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

In Drupal 8, the `$.once()` functionality has changed under the hood, and the method of setting it has changed on the front end. In Drupal 8, `$.once()` needs to be combined with `$.each()`. You need to change the following part.

```js
$(context).find(".some_element").once("some-arbitrary-but-unique-key", function () {});
```

Instead, you need to use this.

```js
$(context).find(".some_element").once("some-arbitrary-but-unique-key").each(function () {});
```

In Drupal 9, `once()` stopped to be a jQuery function. To use `once()` library, first add *core/once* as dependency of the relevant library in the .libraries.yml file.

```yaml
some_library:
  css:
    ...
  js:
    ...
  dependencies:
    - core/once
```

You can now use `once()` to retrieve a list of elements and loop through them.

```js
const elements = $(context).find(".some_element").once("some-arbitrary-but-unique-key");
elements.each(function () {
  // Do something with the current element.
});
```

Comment: You need to add *core/jquery.once* as dependency in the .libraries.yml file.

Answer (score 6):

Drupal provides the jquery plugin `once()`, which allows you to ensure a function is run only once on any single element. You can use this within your behaviour.

See *Drupal.behaviours* here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview