# Blocking JS from being executed more than once

Tags: 8, javascript

JS lines of code are often executed more than once.
How can this ( annoying ) behaviour be blocked?

```
    (function ($, Drupal) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.recherche = {
    attach: function (context) {    

      var filters = $('.block-facets-ajax');
      filters.wrapAll('<div class="facets-wrap"></div>');
...........
```

what's expected:

```
<div class="facets-wrap">
   <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>
   <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>      
</div>
```

what's happening:

```
<div class="facets-wrap">
<div class="facets-wrap">
<div class="facets-wrap">
<div class="facets-wrap">
<div class="facets-wrap">
<div class="facets-wrap">
      <div class="facets-wrap">
           <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>
           <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>     
        </div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

EDIT: trying to apply the doc given in comments, unsuccesfully

```
Drupal.behaviors.recherche = {
    attach: function (context) {  

      var filters = $('.block-facets-ajax',context);
      filters.once('behave').each(function () {
        $(this).wrapAll('<div class="facets-wrap"></div>');
      });
```

EDIT2 : dependancies added to the library.
        It is not working as it is not entering the .each :

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      console.log('this is logged');
      $('.block-facets-ajax', context).once('myModuleBehavior').each(function () {
        console.log('this is not logged');
        // Apply the myModuleBehavior effect to the elements only once.
        $(this).wrap('<div class="facets-wrap"></div>');
      });

    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

EDITED 3 :
if i remove context in the selector then .each is executed but instead of wrapping all elt together it 's wrapping each element individually.
This is the case no matter i use wrapAll or wrap method.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $('.block-facets-ajax').once('myModuleBehavior').each(function () {
          $(this).wrap('<div class="facets-wrap"></div>');
      });

    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

what i am trying to achieve :

```
  <div class="facets-wrap">
       <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>    
       <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>     
   </div>
```

what's the outcome:

```
  <div class="facets-wrap">
       <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>
  </div>
   <div class="facets-wrap">
       <div class="block-facets-ajax></div>     
   </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery once onload](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244492/jquery-once-onload)

Comment: With .once(), see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: i am aware on once() but cannot always make it to work. For example where to place it in this case ?

Comment: First apply the js code only on `context`, then use once(), see the same doc.

Comment: does not work as edited

Comment: Still wrong, follow the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I adjusted your code to match the one from the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview).

#### MYMODULE/js/myscripts.js:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $('.block-facets-ajax', context).once('myModuleBehavior').each(function () {
        // Apply the myModuleBehavior effect to the elements only once.
        $(this).wrapAll('<div class="facets-wrap"></div>');
      });

    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

---

To get that working properly you also need to require `core/jquery.once` for this script.

#### MYMODULE.libraries.yml:

```
myscripts:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/myscripts.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

Comment: not entering the .each as edited !?

Comment: @Matoeil – .each is there.

Comment: i am saying i have pasted your code and console.log is telling me i am not entering that function

Comment: @Matoeil – But outside the function console.log gets called?

Comment: yes it is called outside of the .each

Comment: You need to show us your current code. Add it as an update to your original post.

Comment: @Matoeil – I switched `wrapAll()` with `wrap()`. But seems you need switch back to `wrapAll()`. Updated answer. Actually I misunderstood `wrapAll()`.

Comment: i have edited it . Thanks for your patience and help