# How to use the Vanilla JS version of Drupal Once

Tags: javascript, 9

Once again i am having a problem with the JS called more than once.
the code here transform the select/options of the exposed filters to ul/li.
The problem is that the

> console.log("enter init")

is called many times , when i would need it to be called only once on load :

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  /**
   *
   * Retourne la valeur correspondante du localstorage
   *
   * @param {string} key
   * @return {string}
   */
  function getFromLocalStorage(key) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, "All");
    }
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  }

  const variables = {
    selectElement /** @type={HTMLElement} */: document.querySelector(
      ".views-exposed-form .form-select"
    ),
    optionElements /** @type={HTMLCollection} */: document.querySelector(
      ".views-exposed-form .form-select"
    ).children,
    inputElement /** @type={HTMLElement} */: document.querySelector(
      ".views-exposed-form .form-submit"
    ),
    selectedFilter: getFromLocalStorage("data-value"),
    ul: document.createElement("ul")
  };

  /**
   * Stocke le li clické
   *
   * @param {Event } e
   * @return {void}
   */
  function setToLocalStorageOnClick(e) {
    variables.selectedFilter = e.target.dataset.value;
    localStorage.setItem("data-value", variables.selectedFilter);
  }

  /**
   * Convertit select/option to ul/li
   * Affranchit de l'usage du submit bouton
   * Mémoire des clicks
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function selectToUlFilter() {
    variables.inputElement.classList.add("visually-hidden");
    variables.selectElement.hidden = true;
    variables.ul.setAttribute("class", "selectlist");
    Array.from(variables.optionElements).forEach(item => {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      li.setAttribute("class", "selectlist-option");
      li.dataset.value = item.value;
      li.innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
      variables.ul.append(li);
    });
    variables.selectElement.after(variables.ul);
  }

  /**
   * Transpose le li sélectionné au select/option avant le submit
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function transposeModifToSelect() {
    Array.from(variables.optionElements).forEach(item => {
      if (item.value === variables.selectedFilter) {
        item.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
      } else {
        item.removeAttribute("selected");
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Ajout d'un attribut à l'element sélectionné pour le css
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function addSelectedAttribute() {
    document.querySelector(
      `li[data-value="${variables.selectedFilter}"]`
    ).dataset.selected = "true";
  }

  /**
   * Default controller appelé au chargement de la page
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function init() {
    console.log(drupalSettings.amu_bef_selectors);
    console.log("enter init");

    selectToUlFilter();
    addSelectedAttribute();
    transposeModifToSelect();

    variables.inputElement.click();

    const newUl = document.querySelector(".selectlist");
    const liDefaultEN = document.querySelector(
      '.lang--en li[data-value="All"]'
    );
    if (liDefaultEN) {
      liDefaultEN.innerHTML("All");
    }
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.bef = {
    attach(newUl) {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init(), { once: true });

      newUl.addEventListener(
        "click",
        e => {
          setToLocalStorageOnClick(e);
          transposeModifToSelect();
          variables.inputElement.click();
        },
        { once: true }
      );
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

EDIT:

- if (!initialised) added
- what happen then is eventlistener is not working on : variables.inputElement.click() : error Form submission canceled because the form is not connected.

  ```
  (function($, Drupal) {
  /**
   *
   * Retourne la valeur correspondante du localstorage
   *
   * @param {string} key
   * @return {string}
   */
  function getFromLocalStorage(key) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, "All");
    }
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  }

  const variables = {
    selectElement /** @type={HTMLElement} */: document.querySelector(
      ".views-exposed-form .form-select"
    ),
    optionElements /** @type={HTMLCollection} */: document.querySelector(
      ".views-exposed-form .form-select"
    ).children,
    inputElement /** @type={HTMLElement} */: document.querySelector(
      ".views-exposed-form .form-submit"
    ),
    selectedFilter: getFromLocalStorage("data-value"),
    ul: document.createElement("ul")
  };

  /**
   * Stocke le li clické
   *
   * @param {Event } e
   * @return {void}
   */
  function setToLocalStorageOnClick(e) {
    variables.selectedFilter = e.target.dataset.value;
    localStorage.setItem("data-value", variables.selectedFilter);
  }

  /**
   * Convertit select/option to ul/li
   * Affranchit de l'usage du submit bouton
   * Mémoire des clicks
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function selectToUlFilter() {
    console.log("enter selectToul");
    // variables.inputElement.classList.add("visually-hidden");
    // variables.selectElement.hidden = true;
    variables.ul.setAttribute("class", "selectlist");
    Array.from(variables.optionElements).forEach(item => {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      li.setAttribute("class", "selectlist-option");
      li.dataset.value = item.value;
      li.innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
      variables.ul.append(li);
    });
    variables.selectElement.after(variables.ul);
  }

  /**
   * Transpose le li sélectionné au select/option avant le submit
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function transposeModifToSelect() {
    Array.from(variables.optionElements).forEach(item => {
      if (item.value === variables.selectedFilter) {
        item.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
      } else {
        item.removeAttribute("selected");
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Ajout d'un attribut à l'element sélectionné pour le css
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function addSelectedAttribute() {
    const selectedLi = document.querySelector(
      `li[data-value="${variables.selectedFilter}"]`
    );
    if (selectedLi !== null) {
      selectedLi.dataset.selected = "true";
    }
  }

  /**
   * Default controller appelé au chargement de la page
   *
   * @return {void}
   */
  function init() {
    console.log(drupalSettings.amu_bef_selectors);
    console.log("enter init");

    selectToUlFilter();
    addSelectedAttribute();
    transposeModifToSelect();
    // variables.inputElement.click();

    const liDefaultEN = document.querySelector(
      '.lang--en li[data-value="All"]'
    );
    if (liDefaultEN) {
      liDefaultEN.innerHTML("All");
    }
  }

  const form = document.querySelector(".views-exposed-form");
  form.addEventListener("click", e => {
    setToLocalStorageOnClick(e);
    transposeModifToSelect();
    // works but no ajax
    form.submit();
    // when this does not work : Form submission canceled because the form is not connected
    // variables.inputElement.click();
  });

  let initialised = false;
  Drupal.behaviors.bef = {
    attach() {
      if (!initialised) {
        initialised = true;
        init();
      }
    }
  };
  ```

  })(jQuery, Drupal);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery once onload](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244492/jquery-once-onload)

Comment: Do you try to avoid jQuery? If not add `- core/jquery.once` to the dependency of the library and then use as outlined in the other answer, it has a snippet for D8&+ in the bottom. Also explained in more detail in the [official docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview).

Comment: @leymannx no, because i would need a native js solution and also because i am hoping there's a solution not having to put a once() on every lines of code

Comment: You don't put the once on every line of code. You just put it once. 

Okay, so is the question actually "How can I refactor jQuery once with Vanilla JS"? Then I guess this is off-topic...

Comment: Once is applied to the context, it is not needed multiple times in a behavior. A reason to follow the official docs in this respect is so you do not get bit by ajax or bigpipe etc later. https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview#s-drupalbehaviors

Comment: You might be overthinking this, a simple approach will suffice, some variation of: `var initialised = false; if (!initialised) { initialised = true; // Now run your code }`

Comment: Oh, and `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init(), { once: true });` is wrong - you shouldn't invoke `init`, just pass it. You don't even need that line, the DOM is guaranteed to be loaded when behaviors are invoked so you can replace it with `init();`

Comment: what would be the only line with once() on this code? , or where to place the initialised var?. I have tried and i don't really get it

Comment: i have edited the code, if init() is loaded once , then the clicklistener does not work anymore when triggering the input submit()

Answer (score 5):

There is now a vanilla version of Drupal once (https://www.drupal.org/project/once) and I've been using it successfully on a Drupal 9 project with vanilla JS in my theme. You can look at [the change log here](https://www.drupal.org/node/3158256) and [the original issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2402103) that was the impetus for converting to vanilla. [The source file in the project](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/once/-/blob/1.0.x/src/once.js#L1-29) from which you can build sheds some insight on its use.

In your code above, I see you are using `document.querySelector` and you'll want to pay attention to that as I found a bug as noted here. "[Error when context.querySelector() doesn't find an element on the page](https://www.drupal.org/project/once/issues/3204168)".

The [documentation](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/once/-/blob/1.0.x/src/once.js#L24-27) says:

```
 // once methods always return an array, to simplify the use with a single
 *   // element use destructuring or the shift method.
 *   const [myElement] = once('my-once-id', document.body);
 *   const myElement = once('my-once-id', document.body).shift();
```

So in the end, it's probably best for a single element to use an id with the patch linked to herein rather than `document.querySelector`. For example, I have a single element I want to target so I do it like this:

```
const glossary_view_conditions = once('glossary-view-once', '#views-exposed-form-scs-conditions-block');
```

For multiple elements being targeted, `querySelectorAll` works great. You'll also need your main function to target once, beginning and end. So an example would be:

```
(function (Drupal, once) {
  Drupal.behaviors.customCheckboxes = {
    attach(context) {
      // Find checkboxes, add markup.
      let outer_checkboxes = once('yay-only-once', context.querySelectorAll('.js-form-type-checkbox'));
      // Loop through each matched element.
      for (let i = 0; i < outer_checkboxes.length; i++) {
        // This is similar to jquery $(this).find('input.form-checkbox).
        let inner_inputs = outer_checkboxes[i].querySelectorAll("input.form-checkbox");
        // This is similar to jquery .after().
        // Since querySelectorAll returns a collection, we target with [0].
        inner_inputs[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="checkbox-toggle"><span class="checkbox-toggle__inner"></span></span>');
      }
    }
  };
}(Drupal, once));
```